# How to convert image into numerical array(numpy)?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have image like this[image]

I would like to convert six distinct regions into numerical values.Is there any option for this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open(sample_path.bmp)
p = np.array(im)
```

From there you can do normal array operations on the image.